# Xcode warning: Format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int _Nullable'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I get this warning for the following line of code:

```
    NSLog(@"selected segment: %li", _segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
```

The property `selectedSegmentIndex` is of type `NSInteger`.

If I change the format to `%i` i get the following warning:

```
Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long _Nullable'
```

Are there any new format specifiers for Nullable types or is this just a bug in Xcode 7?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should type:

```
NSLog(@"selected segment: %li", (long)_segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
```

Because NSInteger has a different length in 32 and 64bit architecture. Previously you didn't see the warning, because probably you was compiling only against 64 bit architecture.

---

I'd also advise to read [Apple Article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25), as there are new specifiers in Xcode 7 (among others `nullable` and `nonnull`).

---

To answer your doubts from the comment, please refer to this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html), where they state the following:

> Type Specifiers
>
> Script action: Warns about potential problems; may generate false negatives.
>
> Typically, in 32-bit code you use the %d specifier to format int
>   values in functions such as printf, NSAssert, and NSLog, and in
>   methods such as stringWithFormat:. But with NSInteger, which on 64-bit
>   architectures is the same size as long, you need to use the %ld
>   specifier. Unless you are building 32-bit like 64-bit, these
>   specifiers generates compiler warnings in 32-bit mode. To avoid this
>   problem, you can cast the values to long or unsigned long, as
>   appropriate. For example:
>
> ```
> NSInteger i = 34;
> printf("%ld\n", (long)i);
> ```

Comment: Well that makes the warning go away, but iOS is on 64bit for quite a while and I can't remember having to cast arguments in an NSLog. Changing the format specifier from %i to %li was enough in the past.

Comment: @bbjay Please revise my updated answer, where I pasted code snippet from Apple. They do the same. The warning was always there. You probably compiled mostly for 64bit so you didn't see this warning. If you had compiled on 32bit you'd have seen it previously. The only difference is that in Xcode 7 the warnings are visible all the time, not depending on target architecture.

Comment: Indeed. The reason is that build settings for architectures default to `ARCHS = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)";` which in Xcode 7 has the value `armv7, arm64`. Can you include that information in your answer? I will gladly accept it then.

Comment: @bbjay Xcode 6 had the value of `armv7` & `arm64` too.

Comment: With Xcode 7.2 I'm getting compiler warnings for %ld matching NSInteger that show only when building to older phones: iPhone 5 and 4s. The FixIt recommendation is %d, which solves on iPhone 4s & 5, but causes its own warning on the more recent devices. %td seems to fix it on all targets. Xcode bug, maybe?

Comment: @Richard If you cast your NSInteger to long and format it as %ld, as provided in the example, you should not get any warnings. Confirmed by my Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Thanks @vive... I guess my real issue is why Xcode doesn't suggest this as its fix?

Comment: @Richard Ask Apple ;) Anyway, it depends on your target settings. If you set your target to only 64bit, you don't have to think about this warning. All this stuff is when you support both architectures. Maybe it was an overhead for Apple to check specific project settings - idk, I don't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add :
I got this warning "suddenly" even when I did not change the code that made the warning for long time, and I did not understand why it's appear.

The reason : "Generic iOS Device".
when selected device or simulator, the warnings disappear.

still, I add to the NSLog   "(long)" to the variables. till then I only had "%ld", that turn the warning no matter what was selected (generic device, real device, simulator)